# If my component is invoked by selector with nested elements, can I access and manipulate those nested elements from nsAfterViewInit?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to create a custom layout component.  Ideally, this component can work similarly to GridLayout with my custom features based on the user providing additional tags to nested elements..  But, I'm not finding the nested elements.

sPecifically,
`let childCount = this.getChildrenCount();` returns 0 in ngAfterViewInit.

- I tried this both with and without extending GridLayout
- I cannot remove the template specification without a compile error.

This is a different approach to the same problem I am trying to solve with my other post [How do I load a Nativescript Angular child component using code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165400/how-do-i-load-a-nativescript-angular-child-component-using-code-behind)

The first approach attempts to build the elements in the layout component (similar to RadDataForm), where this approach allows the caller to build the elements, and then tries to find and manage them within the layout component.

Any help on either path would be deeply appreciated!

### Sample user component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ns-app',
    template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <LayoutComponent columns="*, *" rows="auto" >
            <TextField [text]="name" hint="name" row="1" col="1"></TextField>
            <TextField [text]="type" hint="type" row="2" col="1"></TextField>
            <Button text="Add" row="4" col="2"></Button>
        </LayoutComponent>
    </StackLayout>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    type: string;

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("in ngOnInit for AppComponent");
        this.name = '';
        this.type = '';
    }
}
```

### My simple Layout Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GridLayout, GridUnitType, ItemSpec } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/grid-layout";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'LayoutComponent',
    template: ''
})
export class LayoutComponent extends GridLayout implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor() { super() }
    ngOnInit() {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
let childCount = this.getChildrenCount();
        console.log(`In LayoutComponent ngAfterViewInit with Grid contains ${childCount} kids`);
        for(let i=0; i < childCount; i++ ) {
            let child = this.getChildAt(i);
            console.log(`child ${i} on row ${child.row} =${child}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformat the post

Comment: Thanks for the feedback John.  I am blind, and was totally unaware that the formatting had gone wonky.  Got my wife to look at this attempt, so hopefully, it is better.  Looking at the other post as well.  What else can I do to help you help me?

Comment: Angular's site has a section Dyanamic Component Loader. 
 https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loading

Answer (score 0):

I have found an acceptable solution to my question based on experimenting and digging through several references, including John's.

Rather than nest my elements within my own custom layout component, I can nest them inside a GridLayout, set an id on that GridLayout, and then pass that id to my custom layout component.  My layout component can access the GridLayout using the id, harvest the elements using metadata attributes, and then manage the GridLayout and contained elements from there.
My complete sample is posted on GitHub
https://github.com/jeff-wheatley/LoadComponentSample

### Caller's Template

```
template: `
  <StackLayout height="500">
    <GridLayout id="MyForm" columns="*, *" height="300" width="200">
      <TextField property="email" type="email" required="true"></TextField>
      <TextField property="password" type="password" required="true"></TextField>
      <ListPicker property="choice" [valList]="choices" height="40"></ListPicker>
    </GridLayout>
    <LayoutForm [source]="myObject" form="MyForm" submitLabel="SaveForm" [submitTap]="onSubmitTap()"></LayoutForm>
  </StackLayout>
`})
    `

Note that nativescript makes no complaint that the typical attributes are missing and unexpected ones are present for TextField and ListPicker.  The LayoutComponent uses the specified attributes to understand how to source bind, present and validate each property element.  It also sets needed attributes on each element within ngOnInit before the view is rendered.

This leaves most of the work of handling form processing to the LayoutComponent, where I wanted it to be.  My sample does a basic pass at layout and type support.  It could be expanded to support many more element types such as filtered pick lists, multi-pickers, sliders, checkbox, etc.  It also shows validation fitting in, but does not implement the service.  

Finally, the specifics of getting the GridLayout by id, walking through the nested elements, processing attributes, adding rows and elements to the grid are not technically complex, but I believe the example may better explain the approach vs. my attempting to explain here.  The code is reasonably documented.
```